# Get value from String - Java

Tags: java, soap

I get a response from the server.

```
SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(msgRequest, targetEndpoint);
```

How do I get the documentId value?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <retrieveDocumentRequest>
         <documentId>Test</documentId>
      </retrieveDocumentRequest>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```
...
SOAPBody soapBody = soapResponse.getSOAPBody(); //get body instance from your response

NodeList nodes = soapBody.getElementsByTagName("documentId"); //get documentId property from your body 
String documentId = null;
Node node = nodes.item(0); //match the first correspondence
documentId = node != null ? node.getTextContent() : ""; //check if is null otherwise return your match
...
```